# I dont know why this random quote generator shows undefined most often

Tags: javascript, quotes

Why does the following code show `undefined` most of the time?

```
var fragOne = ["From morning until night", "Most pastors in church", "Hollywood movies in the 21st century", "Never disrespect anyone unless"];

var fragTwo = ["start after the weekend", "the Christians nowadays", "my friend Jacob in Class", "because of snowfall during winter"];

var fragThree = ["some girls in the class.", "intelligent Pilots in the UK.", "Several girls in my complex.", "If I believe in God."];

var button = document.getElementById("btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var displaying = document.getElementById("display");

    var randomOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*fragOne.length);
    var randomTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*fragTwo.length);
    var randomThree = Math.floor(Math.random()*fragThree.length);
    var combineRandom = randomOne+randomTwo+randomThree;

    display.innerHTML = fragOne[combineRandom]+" "+fragTwo[combineRandom]+" "+fragThree[combineRandom];
    console.log(fragOne[combineRandom]+" "+fragTwo[combineRandom]+" "+fragThree[combineRandom]);

});
```

Comment: debug your code and you will see why. Hint: you don't want to index by combineRandom but to combine the strings `combineRandom = fragOne[randomOne] + fragTwo[randomTwo] + fragThree[randomThree]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to take the random index and get the value from the array.

```
var combineRandom = fragOne[randomOne] + " " + fragTwo[randomTwo] + " " + fragThree[randomThree];

display.innerHTML = combineRandom;
console.log(combineRandom);
```

As it was written, you add all random indices and use it for any array for getting an element. The reason for getting `undefined` is, your index is maybe greater then the array has items. It is the usual behaviour with arrays or object and an undefined property to get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You sum three numbers `randomOne`, `randomTwo` and `randomThree` that all can take values from 0 to 1 (`Math.random` returns a value between 0 and 1 and is multiplied by array length which is 4). So you can easily exceed the array's length if you address the element at the index that is a sum of those three, hence why you get the `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in the code you dont need to add up the random numbers just use each to fetch the random quote see below:

this code is not needed:

```
 var combineRandom = randomOne+randomTwo+randomThree;
```

just do this and adapt for your html render

```
 console.log(fragOne[randomOne]+" "+fragTwo[randomTwo]+" "+fragThree[randomTh`ree]);
```